# C Programming: How do I play audio files?

Tags: c, audio, command, mp3

Ok, so I've googled this with no luck (I'm at school :( ), Basically, I want to be able to play a sound file when I do a certain action, but I don't know the command.

I've been told I need to get some mp3 files in the same folder, that's fine, I assume it's the same as opening a file?

Comment: There is no standard way in C to play audio. You must use operating system-specific functionality. Do you see the problem with your question, now?

Comment: @unwind Cool, but there's no way I would have known that before-hand.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, there are no built in function. You can however call a program, vlc for instance and give it your file to read that will do the job.
Call the shell function and enter the bash command : `vlc my_file`. 
The shell function will depend on you OS.